# Access Asp.NET controls in page PreInit event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have below markup in my Content Page default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBody" runat="server">
  <asp:label ID="label1" runat="server"></label>
</asp:Content>
```

When accessing the label in PreInit event, Error shown is- object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Inside PreInit";
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?  Is there a way to get the Asp.NET Web Controls in Page PreInit event ?

Answer (score 3):

No. `PreInit` is the wrong place. According to MSDN, the controls are initialized then `Init` is called.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events

You should consider reworking your logic to pass any data off to `Init`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can access the Content Page Controls in Pages's `PreInit` event.

*Understand that this is NOT the recommended way. See the answer by Daniel.*

Access the [**`Page.Master`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in your `Page_PreInit` event, after that you can access all your Content Page Controls as usual :

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MasterPage master = this.Master; 

            // Access any control of Content Page now ....
            label1.Text = "Inside PreInit";

        }
    }
```

Why it works:
Once the Master property of Page is accessed  it makes a call to `CreateChildControls()` and therefore the Controls get initialized and NO more object references error.